# Обособление сочетания "во всяком случае"

Tags: пунктуация

В первом абзаце рассказа Бориса Виана «Водопроводчик» есть предложение:
*«Звонок был очень выразительный: весомый, чтоб не сказать веский, нет, скорее полновесный… **во всяком случае** неторопливый и внушительный».*

Мне кажется, что после слова «случае» должна стоять запятая; таким образом, предложение должно выглядеть следующим образом:
*«Звонок был очень выразительный: весомый, чтоб не сказать веский, нет, скорее полновесный… **во всяком случае**, неторопливый и внушительный».*

Так или нет?  Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Звонок был очень выразительный: весомый, чтоб не сказать веский, нет, скорее полновесный… **во всяком случае**, неторопливый и внушительный.*

Действительно, вы правы, здесь явно выраженное **вводное** значение у сочетания ***во всяком случае*** (как по смыслу, так и по интонации и структуре предложения).
Вводное сочетание ***во всяком случае***  имеет значение **достоверной оценки**, что видно из содержания предложения.

**Выразительный** – это какой?  Весомый, веский, полновесный –  такие оценки  выглядят нестандартно,  имеют  переносное значение,  поэтому читатель  может не понять смысла. И тогда автор переходит к оценке более ясной, к той, в которой он уверен, поэтому используется оценочное вводное слово ***во всяком случае.***

**Неторопливый, внушительный**  – это уже более объективная оценка, она делается как бы по длительности звонка.  Он не короткий и резкий, но в то же время и не длинный, без настойчивости.  Уверенное нажатие кнопки, поэтому и показался звонок внушительным.

Итак, ***во всяком случае***  выражает здесь оценку  подобранных слов. По Розенталю,  это  **ограничительно-оценочное значение**.  Мы как бы обозначаем границу достоверности сказанного.

**В устной речи** вводное слово выделено паузой и имеет вставочную интонацию (это общий пониженный тон и немного ускоренный темп произношения).

Вводное сочетание  ***во всяком случае***  всегда обособляется, но его нужно отличать от необособленного **парного обстоятельства**.  Сделать это несложно, так как  оценку достоверности обстоятельство не выражает. Сочетание ***во всяком случае***    имеет значение  «при любых обстоятельствах, в любом случае»,   при этом в  предыдущем тексте эти случаи обычно **перечисляются**.  Также обстоятельственное сочетание  входит в основной состав предложения и выделяется **логическим ударением**.

Надо сказать, что вводное слово ***во всяком случае***  в современном языке применяется намного чаще, чем парное обстоятельство.

**Правило Розенталя:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

6. Сочетание *во всяком случае* является вводным и выделяется запятыми, если имеет ограничительно-оценочное значение: ***Во всяком случае**, фамилия его была не Акундин* (А. Т.); *Я, **во всяком случае**, этого не утверждал;* В значении же «при любых обстоятельствах» сочетание во всяком случае вводным не является и запятыми не выделяется:  *Я был уверен, что **во всЯком случае** встречу его сегодня у мамы* (Дост.).

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ** (сравнение сочетаний  ***во всяком случае*** и  ***по крайней мере)***

**ПО КРАЙНЕЙ МЕРЕ,** вводное сочетание.  Выражает уверенность в достоверности сказанного; то же, что «во всяком случае». **ВО ВСЯКОМ СЛУЧАЕ**, вводное сочетание, То же, что «по крайней мере».

Итак, Грамота.ру обозначает одно через другое, то есть Х через Y, а Y через Х, что  не слишком помогает при определении значения вводности.  Также отметим, что эти сочетания отнюдь **не являются полными синонимами** и не всегда заменяют друг друга.

Откуда вообще  берется  оценочное  значение  у по крайней мере? Граница  достоверности  здесь «измеренная», будто определенная **по шкале с обозначением «крайняя мера».**  Возможно, это вводное  сочетание используется при оценке понятий,  достаточно **близких** по смыслу, которые укладываются в эту шкалу.

А вот отличить вводное слово **от парного обстоятельства** в этом случае сложнее. Сравним, к примеру,  два  очень похожих варианта, приведенных в Справочнике по пунктуации. Вводное слово: *В Москве последний счастливый день Мити был девятого марта. Так, **по крайней мере**, казалось ему.*  Обстоятельство:  *На нем появились даже краски, в глазах блеск, что-то вроде отваги или **по крайней мере** самоуверенности*.

Похоже, что варианты различаются не по смыслу, **а по возможности обособления,** то есть зависят от структуры предложения. Так, в последнем примере  используется перечислительная интонация для однородных членов, поэтому сочетание сложно обособить.